# TGF Graph creating and viewing

Tags: java, graph

I have some questions related to creating and displaying a graph created with the `TGF` extension.

Is it enough to describe my graph in this manner into a blank file with the `.TGF` extension ?

```
1 First node
2 Second node
#
1 2 Edge between the two
```

Is it enough to write it like this from Java into that file ?

Also how am i supposed to view the graph's drawing ? I have no clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TGF files require this information only. I have created such graphs with these information alone. Maybe some one else can give a clearer answer. :) 
 When it comes to view the graph, you can use yEd graph Editor (http://www.yworks.com/en/downloads.html#yEd)
 As a start, open the graph with yed. Set **Tools -> Fit Nod to Label** and then use an appropriate layout from Layout menu. Ex: **Layout -> Hierarchical -> Orientation -> Top to Bottoom -> OK**

 Seems TGF format is not expected to keep information about the formation of the graph unlike other complex formats such as GraphML

Answer (score 0):

In adition to [@isuru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1264666/isuru-chathuranga) answer:
If you use this file:

```
0 R0
1 R1
2 R2
3 R3
4 R4
5 R5
6 R6
# 
0 1 1
1 4 1
1 5 1
2 3 1
3 6 1
5 6 1 
6 1 1
6 2 1
```

You will get the following plot (the router icon is my default icon).

[image: resulting network]